# Android problem: ReferenceError: WebAssembly is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, rpgmakermv

I used RPG Maker MZ to export a game that I want to put onto my android phone. I have Android 5.1 installed. When I finally got the app to run on my phone, a screen displays an error

> ReferenceError WebAssembly is not defined

I am using the Active Build Variant zz_crosswalkDebug as the tutorial told me that I needed to use to make it work. That is where I got the screen with the

> ReferenceError WebAssembly is not defined

When I used debug mode I noticed I got the same message but it pointed to a vorbisdecoder.js file. When clicking on the file path it said that Android Studio couldn't find it. But I was still able to look at it. On the top of the screen it says *js files are supported with intellij ultimate.

What can I do to fix this problem?

I think It may have something to do with the build variant I am using or the js files.